# Posting Text from Entry to server side

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, http-post

Suppose am having this URL for which is used to post data to the server

http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.aspx?title=oneIsGone&details=TheyWereTwo

**and am having 2 entries**

```
 <Entry Placeholder="News Title" Margin="8" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="title_entry" HeightRequest="40" />
            <Entry Placeholder="News Details" Margin="8" VerticalOptions="Center"  x:Name="details_entry" HeightRequest="90" />
```

how can i make an async method to post the data typed in the Entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of trigger to start the post, so let's introduce a button as well;

```
<StackLayout>
    <Entry Placeholder="News Title" Margin="8" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="title_entry" HeightRequest="40" />
    <Entry Placeholder="News Details" Margin="8" VerticalOptions="Center"  x:Name="details_entry" HeightRequest="90" />
    <Button Text="Post away!" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" />
</StackLayout>
```

Then in your `Handle_Clicked` method, add some code similar to this:

```
private async void Handle_Clicked (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient ()) {
        var response = await client.GetAsync ($"http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.aspx?title={title_entry.Text}&details={details_entry.Text}");

        // TODO do something with response
    }
}
```

Of course this needs a lot of error handling and such, but this is the basics to get you started.

For some very basic error handling, exceptions etc. just add a try/catch block, like this:

```
private async void Handle_Clicked (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient ()) {
            var response = await client.GetAsync ($"http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.aspx?title={title_entry.Text}&details={details_entry.Text}");

            // TODO do something with response
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Gerald , but how can handle errors here like WebException error  on IOS using Xamarin.forms?

Comment: Have a look at the updated answer. But these are very basic development questions. Although I don't mind to help you get started, StackOverflow is not really the place for these questions. Have a look at some blogs or tutorials that describe these kinds of stuff. Nevertheless, I hope it helped!

Comment: Yeah it helped so much , so if i use this try and catch , it will neglect the webexception in IOS

Comment: I'm not sure what exception you are talking about exactly. But maybe you are referring to the fact that you cannot load HTTP resources from iOS. In regard to that, look at [this link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/ats/#Configuring_ATS_Options). Although your best option is of course to go over to HTTPS.

Comment: Yes i read about that , but still it was coming after implementing those solutions, but i havent seen it yet since i caught the Exception

Answer (score 0):

The question is incomplete, but in the backend you can use the below code.

```
var title = title_entry.Text;
var details= details_entry.Text;
string URI = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.aspx";
String myParameters  = String.Format("title={0}&details={1}",title,details);
sendData(URI,myParameters);

public async void sendData(string URI,string myParameters)
{
 using(HttpClient hc = new HttpClient())
 {
    Var response = await hc.PostAsync(URI,new StringContent (myParameters));
 }
}
```